# Check and map IP address to subnet lookup table with SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table that shows IP addresses assigned to equipment belonging to a customer. This table is used to measure user's activity and performance and generated on a regular basis. I would like to map the IP addresses of these customers to customer ID or name. Due to size and multiple IP addresses that can be assigned to the same customer we have to use subnet instead of individual IP addresses.

The report table contains an IPaddress field and the subnet mapping table is something like below.

```html
+-------------+------+-------------------+
| Customer_ID | VLAN |      Subnet       |
+-------------+------+-------------------+
| HARRIS      | 1012 | 10.111.253.46/32  |
| HARRIS      | 1012 | 10.164.20.49/30   |
| HARRIS      | 1012 | 10.223.165.193/28 |
| HARRIS      | 1013 | 10.155.75.128/26  |
| HARRIS      | 1014 | 10.155.75.128/26  |
| HARRIS      | 1330 | 10.121.30.192/27  |
| HARRIS      | 1331 | 10.120.30.192/27  |
| HARRIS      | 1332 | 10.122.30.192/27  |
| HARRIS      | 3910 | 100.104.12.144/32 |
| HARRIS      | 3927 | 10.70.24.233/32   |
| HARRIS      | 3959 | 10.102.11.182/32  |
| HARRIS      | 3966 | 10.98.11.170/32   |
| STEPHANIE   | 1010 | 100.72.0.33/32    |
| STEPHANIE   | 3896 | 10.96.11.169/29   |
| JOE         | 1010 | 100.69.72.10/32   |
| NED         | 1010 | 100.72.255.2/32   |
| ESTHER      | 1010 | 100.72.255.66/32  |
| BEN         | 1010 | 100.72.255.30/32  |
| SHAWN       | 1010 | 100.72.254.230/32 |
| JACK        | 1010 | 1.1.1.7/32        |
| TONY        | 1010 | 100.72.255.242/32 |
| 335553339   | 1010 | 100.72.254.250/32 |
| 335553342   | 1010 | 100.72.254.186/32 |
| 335553343   | 1010 | 100.72.254.238/32 |
| 335553346   | 1010 | 100.72.255.182/32 |
| 335553347   | 1010 | 1.1.1.2/32        |
| 335553348   | 1010 | 100.72.255.82/32  |
| 335553349   | 1010 | 100.72.254.30/32  |
| 335553351   | 1010 | 1.1.1.1/32        |
| 335553352   | 1010 | 100.80.255.174/32 |
| 335553411   | 1010 | 100.72.255.18/32  |
| 335553412   | 1010 | 100.72.255.22/32  |
| 335553413   | 1010 | 100.72.255.253/32 |
| 335553414   | 1010 | 100.72.255.222/32 |
| 335553415   | 1010 | 100.72.255.202/32 |
| 335553416   | 1010 | 100.72.255.210/32 |
| 335553417   | 1010 | 100.72.255.10/32  |
| 335553418   | 1010 | 100.72.255.218/32 |
| 335553419   | 1010 | 100.72.255.206/32 |
| 335553420   | 1010 | 100.72.255.14/32  |
| 335553421   | 1010 | 100.72.255.114/32 |
| 335553431   | 1010 | 100.72.255.166/32 |
| 335553632   | 1010 | 100.72.4.176/32   |
| 335553632   | 3898 | 10.98.0.49/28     |
| RANDY       |  100 | 100.72.5.6/32     |
| RANDY       | 1012 | 10.111.230.41/32  |
| RANDY       | 1012 | 10.164.31.185/30  |
| RANDY       | 1012 | 10.228.5.1/28     |
| RANDY       | 1013 | 10.154.10.0/26    |
| RANDY       | 1014 | 10.154.10.0/26    |
| HASAN       | 1015 | 100.72.8.94/32    |
| HASAN       | 1015 | 100.73.13.56/32   |
| HASAN       | 3910 | 100.104.3.66/32   |
| HASAN       | 3927 | 10.70.7.157/32    |
| HASAN       | 3959 | 10.102.1.228/32   |
| HASAN       | 3966 | 10.98.2.68/32     |
| DICKY       |  100 | 100.72.10.203/32  |
| DICKY       | 3897 | 1.1.1.1/29        |
| RINA        |  100 | 100.73.2.12/32    |
| RINA        | 1430 | 10.64.9.0/27      |
| RINA        | 3910 | 100.104.2.12/32   |
| RINA        | 3927 | 10.70.2.155/32    |
| RINA        | 3959 | 10.102.1.15/32    |
| RINA        | 3959 | 10.104.8.24/29    |
| RINA        | 3966 | 10.98.1.13/32     |
+-------------+------+-------------------+
```

How do I map the addresses in my dynamic table (check if it belongs to which subnet) in an SQL query and then add a column (i.e. left join) showing the associated Customer name?

Thank you for the help

Comment: Can you make modifications to the table?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question?

Comment: I was just thinking that if your table is very large, then it may not be optimal to run queries using functions. If you can add two more columns with min(ip) and max(ip) then you can probably run queries faster, because the function has already been calculated.

Comment: yes, my table is very large. Billions of row and many columns as well. The lookup table for subnet is around 55K row. 

As you said I realize this is not optimal, but not sure what you are referring by min (ip) and max(ip) here.  Are you referring min and max ip in the table itself?

The thing is each customer_id has its own IP ranges (defined by various subnet), unfortunately not the whole, but chunks of subnets.

So, any better suggestion or solution how I can run the query optimally?

Comment: I don't know it BigQuery has triggers, but I meant for every row you have in your table, you could store the calculated value of start_IP and end_IP of that rows particular range. Then your table would have 5 columns in total, instead of 3 now. When your query runs, it could go directly for `between start_IP and end_IP`without having to do the calculation first.

Comment: I think I will need to further comment after the answer threads below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below example for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION SubnetToRange(CIDR STRING)
RETURNS STRUCT<start_IP STRING, end_IP STRING>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  var beg = CIDR.substr(CIDR,CIDR.indexOf('/'));
  var end = beg;
  var off = (1<<(32-parseInt(CIDR.substr(CIDR.indexOf('/')+1))))-1; 
  var sub = beg.split('.').map(function(a){return parseInt(a)});
  var buf = new ArrayBuffer(4); 
  var i32 = new Uint32Array(buf);
  i32[0]  = (sub[0]<<24) + (sub[1]<<16) + (sub[2]<<8) + (sub[3]) + off;
  var end = Array.apply([],new Uint8Array(buf)).reverse().join('.');
  return {start_IP: beg, end_IP: end};
"""; 
SELECT e.*, t.* EXCEPT(start_IP,    end_IP)
FROM `project.dataset.equipments` e,
(
  SELECT s.*, 
    NET.IPV4_TO_INT64(NET.IP_FROM_STRING(start_IP)) AS start_IP,
    NET.IPV4_TO_INT64(NET.IP_FROM_STRING(end_IP)) AS end_IP
  FROM `project.dataset.subnets` s,
  UNNEST([SubnetToRange(Subnet)]) 
) t
WHERE NET.IPV4_TO_INT64(NET.IP_FROM_STRING(IP)) BETWEEN start_IP AND end_IP
```

You can test, play with above using sample/dummy data as in below example

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION SubnetToRange(CIDR STRING)
RETURNS STRUCT<start_IP STRING, end_IP STRING>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  var beg = CIDR.substr(CIDR,CIDR.indexOf('/'));
  var end = beg;
  var off = (1<<(32-parseInt(CIDR.substr(CIDR.indexOf('/')+1))))-1; 
  var sub = beg.split('.').map(function(a){return parseInt(a)});
  var buf = new ArrayBuffer(4); 
  var i32 = new Uint32Array(buf);
  i32[0]  = (sub[0]<<24) + (sub[1]<<16) + (sub[2]<<8) + (sub[3]) + off;
  var end = Array.apply([],new Uint8Array(buf)).reverse().join('.');
  return {start_IP: beg, end_IP: end};
"""; 
WITH `project.dataset.subnets` AS (
  SELECT 'HARRIS' Customer_ID, 1012 VLAN, '10.111.253.46/32' Subnet UNION ALL
  SELECT 'HARRIS', 1012, '10.164.20.49/30' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'HARRIS', 1012, '10.223.165.193/28' UNION ALL
  SELECT '335553632', 3898, '10.98.0.49/28' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'RINA', 1430, '10.64.9.0/27' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'RINA', 3966, '10.98.1.13/32'
), `project.dataset.equipments` AS (
  SELECT 'equipment A' equipment, '10.164.20.50' IP UNION ALL
  SELECT 'equipment B', '10.64.9.0'
)
SELECT e.*, t.* EXCEPT(start_IP,    end_IP)
FROM `project.dataset.equipments` e,
(
  SELECT s.*, 
    NET.IPV4_TO_INT64(NET.IP_FROM_STRING(start_IP)) AS start_IP,
    NET.IPV4_TO_INT64(NET.IP_FROM_STRING(end_IP)) AS end_IP
  FROM `project.dataset.subnets` s,
  UNNEST([SubnetToRange(Subnet)]) 
) t
WHERE NET.IPV4_TO_INT64(NET.IP_FROM_STRING(IP)) BETWEEN start_IP AND end_IP
```

with output

```
Row equipment   IP              Customer_ID VLAN    Subnet          
1   equipment A 10.164.20.50    HARRIS      1012    10.164.20.49/30      
2   equipment B 10.64.9.0       RINA        1430    10.64.9.0/27
```

Comment: Brilliant!
Many Thanks for help!

Comment: sure. glad it worked for you. please also consider voting up the answer (if not yet) :o)

Comment: i see you just unaccepted the answer - any problem with it?

Comment: `project.dataset.subnets` ninics your subnets table, `project.dataset.equipments` mimics your equipments table with IPs - you should use whatever respective tables you have - just remove WITH statement(s) and use your own tables as it is in the first section of the answer

Comment: If I can seek more precise solution here. Let's say I have two tables. Table 1 is the main table that contains IP address, VLAN, region, etc. and Table 2 is the lookup table above.

I would like the output is table B with additional column customer_id and subnet (left join from the lookup table based on subnet)

What would be the right query for this?

Comment: Would it makes sense to precalcute the `start_IP` and `end_IP` and store the results in separate columns? I'm thinking of a trigger for new/updated rows. I'm confused as to whether BigQuery has those.

Comment: @busheriff - I feel like your original question is fully answered. I recommend you to post new question if you have and provide there all related details

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant: Sorry, I feel now my question was answered slightly different from what I was looking for.  

I have table A, which is the primary table that has billions of rows with key information are timestamp, IP address and VLAN, location and service. Table B is the lookup table with a sample that I posted in my original post. 

What I would like to do is simply is to create table C that has all columns from table A and customer_id extracted from lookup table. Adding subnet column in table C is fine but not essential.

Comment: For some reasons, I see this message when running the query

NET.IPV4_TO_INT64() encountered a non-IPv4 address. Expected 4 bytes but got 16

Comment: those NET.* functions support IPv4 addresses - check documentation for more details

Comment: nice answer! note that BQ can handle IP masks and networks without jumping to UDFs https://towardsdatascience.com/geolocation-with-bigquery-de-identify-76-million-ip-addresses-in-20-seconds-e9e652480bd2

Answer (score 0):

A query that looks for IP addresses and subnets, and published in:

- https://towardsdatascience.com/geolocation-with-bigquery-de-identify-76-million-ip-addresses-in-20-seconds-e9e652480bd2

```sql
# replace with your source of IP addresses

WITH source_of_ip_addresses AS (
  SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(contributor_ip, 'xxx', '0')  ip, COUNT(*) c
  FROM `publicdata.samples.wikipedia`
  WHERE contributor_ip IS NOT null  
  GROUP BY 1
)

SELECT country_name, SUM(c) c
FROM (
  SELECT ip, country_name, c
  FROM (
    SELECT *, NET.SAFE_IP_FROM_STRING(ip) & NET.IP_NET_MASK(4, mask) network_bin
    FROM source_of_ip_addresses, UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(9,32)) mask
    WHERE BYTE_LENGTH(NET.SAFE_IP_FROM_STRING(ip)) = 4
  )
  JOIN `fh-bigquery.geocode.201806_geolite2_city_ipv4_locs`  
  USING (network_bin, mask)
)
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

The math here is pretty fast, and doesn't require JS UDFs. Just replace `country_name` with `customer_name`.

Comment: FYI - BigQuery deleted this table, so this answer doesn't work anymore. In the meantime here's my solution for Snowflake https://hoffa.medium.com/free-ip-address-geolocation-with-maxmind-and-snowflake-676e74ea80b8