# Mapping IP address using subnet and vlan lookup table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I raised a similar question in different posting here [Check and map IP address to subnet lookup table with SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59866093/check-and-map-ip-address-to-subnet-lookup-table-with-sql), but after reviewing the results I realize that the situation was slightly more complex;hence it was partially answered. I ran into an issue where many users are incorrectly identified due to VLAN mismatch, which was not considered initially; hence I am posting another follow up question with a bit more detail problem description here:

I have a table that shows IP addresses assigned to equipment belonging to a customer. This table is used to measure user's activity and performance and generated on a regular basis.   The table has IP address and VLAN field, among other fields. Let's say this is table A. It is worth to be noted that multiple IP addresses may be assigned to the same equipment or customer.This table A does not have customer_name so I would like to map the IP address of each customer in this table to customer name or customer_ID, which is located in table B (lookup table). For some reasons the lookup table B uses the subnet instead of individual IP address.

It shall be noted that the mapping has to meet two criteria, and not just simple one to one IP mapping based on subnet.  Both IP address and VLAN in table A have to match both subnet and VLAN in lookup table B, not just IP addresses range within the subnet in table B.  The reason is simply to avoid incorrect match since Table A may have IP address within the same subnet in table B but different VLAN, so the join should be based on these two keys.

Table A has fields something like this:

timestamp,IP address,VLAN, metrics.... 
An example below:

[image]

An example of lookup table B is something like this:

```html
+-------------+------+-------------------+
| Customer_ID | VLAN |      Subnet       |
+-------------+------+-------------------+
| HARRIS      | 1012 | 10.111.253.46/32  |
| HARRIS      | 1012 | 10.164.20.49/30   |
| HARRIS      | 1012 | 10.223.165.193/28 |
| HARRIS      | 1013 | 10.155.75.128/26  |
| HARRIS      | 1014 | 10.155.75.128/26  |
| HARRIS      | 1330 | 10.121.30.192/27  |
| HARRIS      | 1331 | 10.120.30.192/27  |
| HARRIS      | 1332 | 10.122.30.192/27  |
| HARRIS      | 3910 | 100.104.12.144/32 |
| HARRIS      | 3927 | 10.70.24.233/32   |
| HARRIS      | 3959 | 10.102.11.182/32  |
| HARRIS      | 3966 | 10.98.11.170/32   |
| STEPHANIE   | 1010 | 100.72.0.33/32    |
| STEPHANIE   | 3896 | 10.96.11.169/29   |
| JOE         | 1010 | 100.69.72.10/32   |
| NED         | 1010 | 100.72.255.2/32   |
| ESTHER      | 1010 | 100.72.255.66/32  |
| BEN         | 1010 | 100.72.255.30/32  |
| SHAWN       | 1010 | 100.72.254.230/32 |
| JACK        | 1010 | 1.1.1.7/32        |
| TONY        | 1010 | 100.72.255.242/32 |
| Robert      | 1010 | 100.72.254.250/32 |
| Nita        | 1010 | 100.72.254.186/32 |
| Omar        | 1010 | 100.72.254.238/32 |
| Costco      | 1010 | 100.72.255.182/32 |
| Walmart     | 1010 | 1.1.1.2/32        |
| Navy_blue   | 1010 | 100.72.255.82/32  |
| Jet Rider   | 1010 | 100.72.254.30/32  |
| Falcon      | 1010 | 1.1.1.1/32        |
| Silver      | 1010 | 100.80.255.174/32 |
| Morton Ranch| 1010 | 100.72.255.18/32  |
| 335553412   | 1010 | 100.72.255.22/32  |
| 335553413   | 1010 | 100.72.255.253/32 |
| 335553414   | 1010 | 100.72.255.222/32 |
| 335553415   | 1010 | 100.72.255.202/32 |
| 335553416   | 1010 | 100.72.255.210/32 |
| 335553417   | 1010 | 100.72.255.10/32  |
| 335553418   | 1010 | 100.72.255.218/32 |
| 335553419   | 1010 | 100.72.255.206/32 |
| 335553420   | 1010 | 100.72.255.14/32  |
| 335553421   | 1010 | 100.72.255.114/32 |
| 335553431   | 1010 | 100.72.255.166/32 |
| 335553632   | 1010 | 100.72.4.176/32   |
| 335553632   | 3898 | 10.98.0.49/28     |
| RANDY       |  100 | 100.72.5.6/32     |
| RANDY       | 1012 | 10.111.230.41/32  |
| RANDY       | 1012 | 10.164.31.185/30  |
| RANDY       | 1012 | 10.228.5.1/28     |
| RANDY       | 1013 | 10.154.10.0/26    |
| RANDY       | 1014 | 10.154.10.0/26    |
| HASAN       | 1015 | 100.72.8.94/32    |
| HASAN       | 1015 | 100.73.13.56/32   |
| HASAN       | 3910 | 100.104.3.66/32   |
| HASAN       | 3927 | 10.70.7.157/32    |
| HASAN       | 3959 | 10.102.1.228/32   |
| HASAN       | 3966 | 10.98.2.68/32     |
| DICKY       |  100 | 100.72.10.203/32  |
| DICKY       | 3897 | 1.1.1.1/29        |
| RINA        |  100 | 100.73.2.12/32    |
| RINA        | 1430 | 10.64.9.0/27      |
| RINA        | 3910 | 100.104.2.12/32   |
| RINA        | 3927 | 10.70.2.155/32    |
| RINA        | 3959 | 10.102.1.15/32    |
| RINA        | 3959 | 10.104.8.24/29    |
| RINA        | 3966 | 10.98.1.13/32     |
+-------------+------+-------------------+
```

The expected output table is something like below.

timestamp,IP address,VLAN,subnet,customer_name,metrics....

Given billion records need to be processed the query is to be run on BigQuery, so would appreciate inputs and suggestions to make an efficient and optimum query to reduce the long and costly process.

Thank you for help!

Comment: I removed the postgres and mysql tags since the querstion mentions BigQuery. These are 3 different database with different features, and you should always tag only one.

Comment: You should also show sample data for table `A`, along with the results that you expect. I would also probably be a good idea to limit the sample data to the minimum number of rows that can represent your use case.

Comment: i suggest to provide example of BOTH tables: A and B and minimize your sample to just few rows a long with showing expected result based on given example! so we can reproduce your case!

Comment: also, why you are not using extra check on VLAN in the original post/answer you mentioned - sounds like this would make it. No? please explain so we better understand you case

Comment: Can you suggest the additional check in the code please so that it is clearer to me?

Comment: i cannot because it is still not clear what exactly your problem is - from my prospective you just almost repeating your initial question with slightly different wording. as I suggested above - provide better more useful and reasonably sized examples of both tables along with expected result and explain what the problem are - for sure after this we will be able to help - no doubt